# Crossbrowser testing FrontEnd apps in 2022

Tags: javascript, css, front-end, cross-browser

So nowadays, creating js & css that works the same across different browsers is less of an issue as to what it was a few years back.
So let's say I have this Vue app that -

- Has CSS reset
- Include @babel/polyfil
- Doesn't care if it works on Internet Explorer or not
- Not using any special CSS properties

Edit -

- Has browserlist that makes sure I'm not using any css/js that is not supported by a browser that I expect my users to have

Edit 2 -

- I don't care about mobile, users with mobile gets moved to a designated mobile page that disables any further use of the app

Is it really necessary to go over the app on different browsers to check it out?

Comment: It boils down to your tolerance of risk.  Do **you** feel it's worth the effort to validate against multiple browsers vs the cost of failure.  If the worst case scenario is a user sees the page slightly differently but functionality is still present, it might not be worthwhile. However, if the app functionally doesn't work because of a failure, you might consider that to be too great of a risk.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is still necessary to check your application on different browsers. Even though the web is more standardized now than it was in the past, there are still differences between different browsers. For example, some browsers may interpret the same CSS differently, or one browser may have a bug that renders a page differently than the others. Additionally, certain CSS properties may not be supported in certain browsers, so it is still important to test your application in multiple browsers.

Comment: How often does it happen to you that you see discrepancy in different browsers? I've just added another constraint to my question, please tell me if it changed anything

Answer (score 0):

It's not or yes it is, it all depends what you are developing and who your target is. You should look at this from a cost/benefit perspective. For example if 0,005% of your customers uses Internet explorer or safari or whatever, its not worth spending too much time on making sure things are 100% the same in all browsers - it also occupies time that might be used to develop new functionality that you could have put into the market earlier.

So I would say, instead of looking at this from technical point of view, look at this from a business point of view and make sure the extra time you spend on this will generate an extra income and not only do it because "everything has to be perfect"

Comment: When I know they could be differences for different browsers which could break my website, then I should start to look at this from a business perspective. But when I would know for sure when my site runs smoothly on browser X, it will very likely run on browsers Y and Z, then I may be able to spare a hell lot of duplicate testing. I think the OP is after the second part, the technical side, which is a sensible question.

Comment: @DocBrown then the focus should be on what are the differences between  browsers and asking about that and not if it's necessary to do it or not.

Comment: @DocBrown I'd really love to hear your opinion then :)

Comment: @CrazyFrog: maybe, I think the OP is more about which elements to use / not to use so differences between browsers do *not* show up. But that's would be a question way-too-broad to be sensible answerable by the Q&A format of this site.

Comment: @Haim: I am not a real expert on this, but I guess you will see the largest differences when comparing mobile with desktop browsers.

Comment: You are right about the mobile, my app is not designed for mobile and it forces the user to use desktop, I'll add that to the question